# How to get all products in cart Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, cart

How can I get the collection of all products in cart currently ?

Comment: what data need from collection of all products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// retrieve quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// retrieve quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
public function __construct(    
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession            
    ) {   
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;

    }

public function getSCurrentUser(){

      $cartQuote=$this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
      $items=$cartQuote->getAllItems();


        foreach($items as $item) {
             echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
             echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
             echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
             echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
             echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
             echo "<br />";             
        //get all data here
          //print_r($item->getProduct()->getData());        

        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will reply to the question in two parts:

> 1. Where should you change the checkout URL?

The destination in link.phtml is `$block->getCheckoutUrl()`. You should not change the template to change functionality, but change the block Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link instead. To do so create a plugin for it with a method afterGetCheckoutUrl() to change the return value.

> 2. How to get all items in the cart?

As of magento-2.0 the service contracts in Magento_Checkout and Magento_Quote do not provide the necessary methods yet, so we use the cart model. In your plugin inject it like this:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
{
    $this->cart = $cart;
}
```

Now that you have access to the cart, you can retrieve the items in several ways, which is basically the same as in Magento 1:

> $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection()

Returns a quote item collection with all items associated to the current quote.

> $this->cart->getItems()

This is a shortcut for the method above, but if there is no quote it returns an empty array, so you cannot rely on getting a collection instance.

> $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems()

Loads the item collection, then returns an array of all items which are not marked as deleted (i.e. have been removed in the current request).

> $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()

Loads the item collection, then returns an array of all items which are not marked as deleted AND do not have a parent (i.e. you get items for bundled and configurable products but not their associated children). Each array item corresponds to a displayed row in the cart page.

Choose what fits your needs best. In most cases, the last method is what you will need.

Answer (score 0):

[How to get Current cart count in Magento2](https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/how-to-get-current-cart-count-in-magento2/)